# Access SQL: Grab list of forms

Tags: sql, ms-access

In Row Source in an Access List Box, what SQL can grab me the list of Forms in the database?

Answer (score 2):

All the objects in Access are stored in a hidden system table called MsysObjects.  The object type for forms is -32768. So your query would be:

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Name
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE (((MSysObjects.Type)=-32768));
```